# Quantlib python FRA rate helper

Tags: programming, quantlib, bootstrapping

Can i get an example of how to use quantlib python FRAratehelper?

I would like to use it to get discount factors, with 3month Jibar as a reference rate.

Comment: suggest you go to their github or webpage

Answer (score 1):

FraRateHelper has several possible forms of the constructor, but try this:

```
import QuantLib as ql
rate = 0.50
start = 3
euribor6m = ql.Euribor6M()
ql.FraRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), start, euribor6m)
```

Check out a working example (Euribor curve bootstrapping) in the QuantLib Cookbook